# Weak left arm or really strong.. Help Me understand

Tags: biceps, arms

I'm 17 and skinny, I've been doing pushups and tricep exercises for 3 years (only at home) and I have now started lifting heavy bags and buckets for a year.

After workout my right arm feels so strong and stiff and tight all the kind a strong arm feels also it looks bulkier. But the left arm still doesn't look bulkier or feel stiff, it feels too light.

During lifting the left arm also doesn't feel like being strained or overloaded.

Please tell me what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

The feeling in the right arm you feel is your muscle working from the exercises as it should. With an exercise such as push-ups which use both arms to perform it can be extremely easy to let one arm do more work without realising.

When performing the exercise you should really focus on pushing through both arms evenly. In your case your left arm is likely not stronger but is your weaker arm. I would guess from your question that you are right handed?